# How is hardware context switct used/unused in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Old x86 intel architecture provided context switching (in the form of **TSS**) at hardware level. But I have read that,  linux has long "abandoned" using hardware context switching functionality as they were less optimised, less flexible and was not available on all architextures.

What confuses me is how can software (linux) control hardware operations (saving/restoring context)? Linux can choose **not** to use context setup by hardware but hardware context switch would nevertheless happen (making "optimisation" argument irrelevant).

Also if linux is not using hardware context switch, how can then the value **%eip** (pointing to next instruction in **user** program) be saved and kernel stack pointer restored by the kernel? (and vice-versa process)

I think kernel would need some support from hardware to save user program **%eip** and switch **%esp** (user to kernel stack) registers even before interrupt service routine starts.

If this support indeed is provided by hardware then how is linux **not** using hardware context switches?

Terribly confused!!!

Comment: CALL, interrupts, traps, and exceptions save the IP. These are the usual way to enter to kernel (but on boot, but you do no need to save IP there). Then you can just manually save the state of CPU (flags, FPU, etc.)

Comment: The intel protection scheme is quite complex; it was derived from a capability-based object processor, the iapx432.  The `object interfaces` that the iapx 286,386 supported were lessor, and somewhat layered.  At the least layering the Trap and Interrupt Gate function with minimal intrusion -- they switch stacks on the way into the kernel; and the iret undoes the switch on the way back to user land.  So all the kernel has to do is point the tss.sp0 to the task's kernel thread before resuming it, and it behaves fairly normally.

Comment: Hmm. That answers all the doubts but did not understand how is linux "disabling" hardware context switches? What does it actually mean by hardware context switching? Does it mean to simply swap value of register `tr` which points to task TSS? I have briefly read IA32 architecture manual but did not find anything that allows software to disable hardware context switches.

Comment: It's not disabled, it just isn't used.  See https://wiki.osdev.org/Context_Switching